# Polynomial expansion

Tags: polynomials

Question from the **Probability and Computing** book by Mitzenmacher M. and Upfal E.

Given is the following polynomial:
$$F(x)=\prod_{i=1}^d(x-a_i)$$

Then the book says:

> Transforming $F(x)$ to its canonical form by consecutively multiplying
>   the $i$th monomial with the product of the first $i-1$ monomials requires
>   $\Theta(d^2)$ multiplications of coefficients.

Did the authors mean to write $2^d$? If not, what does $\Theta(\cdot)$ mean then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they meant $\Theta(d^2)$.  They describe a process for going from a polynomial of degree $k$ to one of degree $k+1$, or rather, from the coefficients of a degree $k$ polynomial to the coefficients of a degree $k+1$ polynomial.  This takes   $O(k)$ multiplications, and $\sum_{k=1}^dO(k) = \Theta(d^2)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the last part? What is $1^d$?

Comment: A typo on my part, fixed in an edit just now.  Sorry.